# Optoisolator between uC y IR2110?

Tags: microcontroller, power-electronics, brushless-dc-motor, opto-isolator, driver

I am working on a brushless driver, which has 3 IR2110 as a mosfet driver and as a microcontroller I use a stm32f103c8t6 (blue pill board). Everything works correctly, but I have the following question:
Should I connect optocouplers to the output of my uC and to the input of the IR2110 to protect it from possible surges or electrical noise that may be generated in the power circuit?
I attach an image of a single phase, my idea is to put the optoisolators to transmit the HIGH_x and LOW_x signals.
[image: phase a]

Comment: Are they going to use the same +5V and the same GND?

Comment: yes, would that be an inconvenience? Or should I use, for example, a DC DC regulator to isolate the voltages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you share the same ground, an optoisolator serves no purpose: you don't need a functional separation of reference levels, nor do you get any galvanic isolation.

So, no, don't add a superfluous optocoupler.

Comment: Thank you very much for clearing my doubt, this raised 2 questions for me.
1- So in case I want to "isolate" the microcontroller, I would need an isolated power supply only for the uC, is this correct?
2- If the IR2110 burns out and its inputs are short-circuited, for example, and without having an optoisolator, would those uC outputs burn out in the best case scenario?

Comment: 1 - yes, but microcontrollers rarely *need* to be isolated. They're usually the signal *agressors*, not the victims! What they do need is a well-stabilized supply voltage, relative to a reliable ground potential. 2 - why would that happen? That seems like an unlikely failure mode.